# TabView without the tabs

Tags: nativescript

My app displays two views of the same info. Thought I use TabView - but space is as a premium - any way to hide the tab bar itself. I'll do it programmatically via a menu.

I'm not tied to the idea of a TabView. Any other suggestions? Basically need to switch to a different view of the same underlying data.

Comment: you could use `nativescript-slides` plugin to display your content instead `TabView`. `nativescript-slides` allows you to have several views and you could switch between them by swiping. You could find an example in this GitHub repo. -https://github.com/TheOriginalJosh/nativescript-slides

Comment: For related question with more recent answer [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62330541/1225272).

Answer (score 0):

This is the code in one of my existing applications I'm writing; I can't promise the iOS side works as I haven't actually tested this screen in iOS yet, but I believe the code should work for iOS also.

```
exports.onNavigatedTo = function(args) {
  var tabview = args.object.getElementById('tabview');

  if (global.android) {
    tabview._tabLayout.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE);
  } else {
    tabview._ios.tabBar.setHidden(true);
  }
};
```

`

Please note the declarative ui xml file has the tabview element using the id of "tabview", I've got the "onNavigatedTo" event being used and I'm also using my opensource NativeScript-Dom plugin which gives me the "getElementById" function.  However, in this specific case you could easily replace that piece of code by the build in function to get an id from a view...

Comment: I'm getting undefined error on _tabLayout, android.view.. and _ios

Comment: I'm going to assume if you got that error; that first line returned undefined because you didn't have the tabview in the xml have an id of "tabview"...   You will get that error when `var tabview == undefined`

Comment: Actually it's a compile/editor time error - i'm in VS Code. do i have to include a module to get these platform specific definitions.

Comment: Not sure on that -- I use phpStorm so it is a bit smarter about things; the _ indicates it is a private variable; so no typings would be available anyways.   You can wrap in an <any> or (blah as any) to make the typings happy...