# *ngIf not working in ios nativescript-angular

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-angular, nativescript-cli

in **footer** based on ***ngif** condition im **changing footer icons**... its working perfectly in **android** but not in the case of **ios**

```
<Button class="footer-class" textWrap="true" (tap)="onNavItemTap('/profile')" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
<FormattedString>
   <Span fontFamily="FontAwesome" [text]="profile" class="icon-style fa"></Span>
   <Span text="&#x000a;profile" class="footer-title"></Span>
</FormattedString>
</Button>
<Button class="footer-class" textWrap="true" (tap)="onNavItemTap('/contactus')">
   <FormattedString>
      <Span fontFamily="FontAwesome" [text]="contactus" class="icon-style fa"></Span>
      <Span text="&#x000a;contactus" class="footer-title"></Span>
   </FormattedString>
</Button>
```

..[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share ur code please ?

Comment: I have added code with the question

Comment: are you using tabs ?

Comment: if you are using tabview, take alook at this similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/49851342/859968

Comment: nope not using tabviews just using StackLayouts and GridLayouts

Comment: then simply repeat the layouts.. i.e one for loggedin user and one for not loggedin

Comment: npm i tns-core-modules@next --save

Comment: its working now thats for help